# Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting this error on the homepage and the admin page after trying to install an extension that failed.

I have attempted the fixes on the other questions, but I am still getting the error.

I have searched the entire site for a `maintenance.flag` file but it doesn't exist. I have also deleted the session data and cache manually within FTP.

I am still getting this error. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: I have created the /var/log folder with 0777 permissions but no log files are being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the compiler is enabled. Disable the compiler.

Go to:

System->Tools->Compilation

then disable the compilation.